# Trying to convert my matrix into numeric in R

Tags: r

structure of my matrix is like this

```
str(transition2)
 chr [1:7, 1:7] "0.00" "0.00" "0.01" "0.00" "0.05" "0.00" "0.00" "0.15" "0.45" 
"0.18" "0.03" "0.01" "0.06" "0.05" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 ..$ : chr [1:7] "cold" "active.low.value" "active.low.medium.value" 
"active.medium.value" ...
..$ : chr [1:7] "cold" "active.low.value" "active.low.medium.value" 
"active.medium.value" ...
```

When i do the element-wise multiplication, it throws me this error:

```
Error in segments[, i - 1] %*% transition2 : 
 requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

To counter this, i do the following:

```
 transition2<-as.numeric(as.character(transition2))
```

but still the error doesn't go

this is the dput result

```
dput(transition2)
structure(c("0.00", "0.00", "0.01", "0.00", "0.05", "0.00", "0.00", 
"0.15", "0.45", "0.18", "0.03", "0.01", "0.06", "0.05", "0.07", 
 "0.21", "0.43", "0.21", "0.04", "0.01", "0.00", "0.00", "0.05", 
 "0.27", "0.56", "0.24", "0.04", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.04", 
 "0.16", "0.54", "0.20", "0.01", "0.04", "0.00", "0.00", "0.01", 
 "0.12", "0.68", "0.05", "0.74", "0.29", "0.07", "0.03", "0.00", 
 "0.01", "0.89"), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(c("cold", 
 "active.low.value", "active.low.medium.value", "active.medium.value", 
 "active.upper.medium.value", "active.high.value", "inactive"), 
 c("cold", "active.low.value", "active.low.medium.value", 
 "active.medium.value", "active.upper.medium.value", "active.high.value", 
 "inactive")))
```

This is what i am multiplying with

print(segments)

```
                      2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023 2024 2025

 cold                        12   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
 NA

 active low value           408   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
 NA

  active low medium value    546   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
  NA   NA

  active medium value        923   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
  NA   NA

 active upper medium value  578   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
 NA

  active high value          306   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
  NA   NA

  inactive                   227   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
 NA   NA
```

My expected output should be like this

2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023 2024 2025

cold                        12   11   10    9    9    9    8    8    8    8    8

active low value           408  334  299  279  268  261  256  253  250  248  247

active low medium value    546  493  447  413  387  367  351  338  327  319  311

active medium value        923  880  836  794  756  722  693  669  649  631  617

active upper medium value  578  576  568  556  544  532  521  512  503  496  490

active high value          306  313  327  341  355  368  378  387  394  400  405

inactive                   227  392  513  607  681  742  792  834  869  898  923

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: i made the edits, does that help

Comment: `class(transition2) = "numeric"` will convert the matrix to numeric. But how did your matrix become character in the first place?

Comment: `as.numeric` will return a numeric vector. Also, going by your code, you might be multiplying a 7 x 1 column vector by a 7 x 7 matrix, so you should edit that.

Comment: Perfect, it worked. Thank you!